# Re-display table after form submit

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Good afternoon,

I have a simple Django 2.2 application for users to check in equipment they have checked out. A table of users and items they have checked out dominates the top of the page. On the very bottom row, a single text/submit form. I would like this to happen:

1. user enters equipment id and submits
2. page re-displays with: name removed from table (if success), form cleared, success/fail message next to cleared form.

I am close. All of my logic and queries work, my item gets checked back in. However, the page re-renders with no table of users, just the form with the old data still in it.

views.py

```
class EquipmentReturn(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        # get checked out items for display table -this works

        form = ExpressCheckInForm(request.POST)
        return render(request, 'eq_return.html', 
                      context={'master_table': master_table,
                               'form': form}

   def post(self, request):

        if request.method == 'POST'
            form = ExpressCheckInForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

        # this checks the item back in (or not) and creates messages-works

        else:
            form - ExpressCheckInForm()
    return render(request, 'eq_return.html', context={'form': form}
```

I know there is a better way to do this. For instance, my form would not appear until I declared it in the get function. How can I make all of this happen on one page? Thanks!

Comment: From what I can see, you are not passing the `master_table` on the context when returning from the POST. Can you add the 'eq_return.html'? 

Also, you don't need to ask if method is "POST", you are already in the `post` method. And maybe this can be done with some other Class based view, like UpdateView or FormView

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I had considered UpdateView. Would that solve this problem? So, to do it this way I would have to write the query logic and pass the table and the form in context in both the get and post methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this might work. I assume that there is missing code here, for example where you get the `master_table`.

```
class EquipmentReturn(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        # get checked out items for display table -this works

        form = ExpressCheckInForm()
        return render(
            request, 'eq_return.html', 
            context={'master_table': master_table, 'form': form},
        )

   def post(self, request):
        form = ExpressCheckInForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # this checks the item back in (or not) and creates messages-works
            # after saving the form or whatever you want, you just need to redirect back
            # to your url. It will call get again and start over
            return HttpResonseRedirect(reverse('your-url-name'))

    return render(request, 'eq_return.html', context={'form': form})
```

It looks like you are still in the function based view mindset. Search differences and how to understand and use class based views.

Comment: Thank you. That worked! I did review CBVs again before I posted and the docs are very good. I will review again, obviously I was confused.